# Using chords in celery for multiple tasks

Tags: python, celery, scheduled-tasks, chord

I am having a problem getting my tasks to register. Here is my code, please help.

```
task.py

from celery_app import app
from celery import chord
from celery import signature

@app.task(bind=True)
def send_email(self):
    chorded_tasks = chord(get_expired_users.s(),notify.s()) #these tasks actually exist#
    chorded_tasks.get()
```

```
runthis.py

import celeryconfig
from celery import Celery
import os


celery = Celery()
celery.config_from_object("celeryconfig")
project_name = os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
celery.send_task(
    "tasks.send_email".format(project_name),
    kwargs={

    },
    args={

    },
```

the code block above is what I am running. It will run fine but it wont actually do the tasks. I also have a file that runs this on a schedule and that works fine as well. I just don't understand why it wont run the actual tasks

Comment: It looks like `"tasks.send_email".format(project_name)` is missing a format-string placeholder -- perhaps an error made when trying to anonymize the code into a shareable example? I'd expect `project_name` to just be discarded.

Comment: that is a mistake on my part, project name is needed and not the issue. Sorry about that. I am more worried about the way I formatted the chord or chorded tasks

Comment: also if you can help me with the error ` AttributeError: type object 'chord' has no attribute 's'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using wrong type for the `args` parameter. It should be a tuple or a list. In your example you are passing a dictionary as args parameter. That could cause the problem you are having. Considering that your task has no arguments something like the following should work: `celery.send_task("tasks.send_email".format(project_name), (), kwargs={})`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. I am now getting an error  `Received unregistered task of type 'tasks.send_email'. The message has been ignored and discarded.`

Comment: I am also getting the error `AttributeError: type object 'chord' has no attribute 's'`

Comment: That error comes from code that you did not show here. The code you did show can't possibly cause that AttributeError.